# Spring JPA Self Reference Issue

Tags: spring, jpa, infinite-loop

I created a table, Category in Postgres which holds both parent and child categories and references to itself (it's a self join table)

The table comprises of following columns: `id, parent_id, start_date, end_date, status`
I also have one row for root parent whose id = 0. So, any first level categories have root as its parent.

Example: Apparel > Women. Here Apparel(id=1) is a first level category whose parent_id = 0. Women is another category whose parent_id = 1.

I am using Spring JpaRepository findAll on my table and this is leading to infinite recursion.

POJO

```
@Table(name = "ofr_category")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Category {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "cat_id", updatable = true, unique = true, nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CATEGORY_SEQ")
  @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "CATEGORY_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "CATEGORY_SEQ")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "cat_name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "cat_status")
  private String status;

  @Column(name = "start_date")
  private LocalDate startDate;

  @Column(name = "end_date")
  private  LocalDate endDate;

  @Column(name = "parent_id")
  private Long parentId;

  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Category parentCategory;

  @JsonManagedReference
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parentCategory")
  private List<Category> childCategories;

  public Category getParentCategory(){
    return parentCategory;
  }

 }
```

Exception seen
`"Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.test.category.dataobject.Category[\"parentCategory\"]->com.test.category.dataobject.Category[\"parentCategory\"]->com.test.category.dataobject.Category[\"parentCategory\"])",`

Comment: This is a Jackson exception, not JPA. It is unable to parse the recursive relationship - you need to tell it how to handle it, and it looks like your JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference annotations aren't being picked up. Maybe move them to the method accessors, as you've told Jackson to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your input Chris. I don't see any exception when I try to access a level 1 categories along with their children. In my example above, if I access apparel, I don't see any issue. The issue occurs when I access the root (id = 0) which is the parent of all level 1 categories. I figured out the issue :( Stupid mistake. I accidentally made the parent of root as 0 which should be null. This was leading to cyclic fetch

Comment: Given my table structure as defined above, what is the best way to fetch the entire tree of categories? I feel like the performance is really bad if I do a find(0) which is a fetch of root element to get the entire tree. Is there an alternative solution? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your JPA provider will have provider specific options, like batch fetching, that might help. See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/solutions/performance001.htm#CHDJFFEJ for an example, those these are usually more difficult on self referencing tables with multiple levels. You may have to try different options and solutions and compare them to see what works best with your use cases and data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look into [@JsonIdentityInfo](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-identity-info-annotation.html), which solved a similar problem for me. You can check if this basic annotation works for you.:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Category {
...
}
```